# VBA Excel Validation: Use of IF-Statements in Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create the Formula1 string for a validation list in VBA.
My goal is to create a drop down list based on a parameter.

[image: | My List of things | Another header | | ----------------- | -------------- | | First | row | | Second | row |]

If I only want the stuff for Person A, then only "Some Stuff" and "Object 3" need to be in that drop down list.

Likewise if I only want the stuff for Person B, then only "Some other Stuff" and "Object 1" shall to be in that drop down list.

I am having trouble wrapping this around in my head... It's almost certainly a "one liner" but it's been too long since I last did some VBA...

NB: The real deal is way more complex than this example. I cannot change the way things are formatted.

Comment: You can do this without vba using helper lists. If you are using 365 then produce these list using the filter function,  example: `=FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5="*")`  then create dependent dropdown lists for each of these: https://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html

Comment: **Where** the mentioned drop down list(s) to be created? Wouldn't it be more convenient to be automatically created when a check in column A:B is done, or removed?

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically create/adapt list validation cells **when an "x" is placed or cleared from B:C columns**, please copy the next code in the respective sheet code module. It creates two list data validation cells in "E2", respective "F2":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastR As Long
    lastR = Me.Range("A" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:C" & lastR)) Is Nothing Then
        If Me.Range("E1").Value = "" Then Me.Range("E1:F1").Value = Array("B Validation", "C Validation")
        Dim arrAC, arrRet, i As Long, k As Long
        
        arrAC = Me.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2
        ReDim arrRet(UBound(arrAC) - 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrAC)
            If arrAC(i, Target.column) = "x" Then arrRet(k) = arrAC(i, 1): k = k + 1
        Next i
        If k > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve arrRet(k - 1)
                With Me.cells(2, Target.column + 3).Validation
                  .Delete
                  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                               Formula1:=Join(arrRet, ",")
                End With
        Else
                 Me.cells(2, Target.column + 3).Validation.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @CAPLDev Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, doesn't it do what you need?